# JFrame program and running another class in Java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, paintcomponent

So currently I want to use a jframe program that would run another class in a window.

A working example:
Jframe:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class FaceJFrame
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(300,400);
        frame.setTitle("A Rectangle Object in a JFrame");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Face aRectangle = new Face();

        frame.add(aRectangle);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The program:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class Face extends JComponent
{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        // Construct face and eyes
        Rectangle face = new Rectangle(0, 0, 50, 50); 
        Rectangle eye = new Rectangle(5, 5, 15, 15);
        Rectangle eye2 = new Rectangle(25, 5, 15, 15);

        //make some lines for the mouth
        Line2D mouth1 = new Line2D.Double(15, 30, 15, 35);
        Line2D mouth2 = new Line2D.Double(15, 35, 35, 35);
        Line2D mouth3 = new Line2D.Double(35, 35, 35, 30); 

        // draw the rectangle
        g2.draw(face); 
        g2.draw(eye);
        g2.draw(eye2);
        g2.draw(mouth1);
        g2.draw(mouth2);
        g2.draw(mouth3);
    }

}
```

With these two code snippets, running the Jframe one in cmd would give a pop-up window with a little face on it.

I want to do the same with the following code:
Jframe:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class Car_JFrame
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(300,400);
        frame.setTitle("a car");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Car aRectangle = new Car();

        frame.add(aRectangle);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

and the main class:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
public class Car
{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        Rectangle body = new Rectangle(0, 10, 60, 20); 

        Line2D roof1 = new Line2D.Double(10, 10, 20, 0);
        Line2D roof2 = new Line2D.Double(20, 0, 40, 0);
        Line2D roof3 = new Line2D.Double(40, 0, 50, 10); 
        Ellipse2D.Double wheel1 = new Ellipse2D.Double(15, 25, 10,10);
        Ellipse2D.Double wheel2 = new Ellipse2D.Double(45, 25, 10,10);
        // draw the rectangle
        g2.draw(body);
        g2.draw(roof1);
        g2.draw(roof2);
        g2.draw(roof3);
        g2.draw(wheel1);
        g2.draw(wheel2);

    }
}
```

It doesn't produce the same result. In fact, running car_jframe in cmd would output the face program. (they're in the same blueJ project)

What should I do?

Comment: Only one class in your application should have a main() method. In this case it would be the class that creates the JFrame. Then you have Car and Face components. You can then add an instance of a Car and/or a Face to the frame when you create the JFrame..

Comment: The Car class does not extend any JComponent derived class, and so your code will fail -- it won't even compile because you can't add a Car instance to a JFrame. Have it extend JPanel or JComponent at least. Either that, or if you want to leave it as a logical and non-component class, then combine it with a JPanel class that can draw it by calling Car's paintComponent within the JPanel's own paintComponent override. Don't forget the `@Override` annotation as well when you *think* that you're over-riding a method (i.e., paintComponent).

Comment: How are you executing the program from the command line?

Comment: @Mad I am doing `java CarJFrame`. when that happens, it executes and shows another program's window

Comment: @RegisteredUser Well, you `Car_JFrame` won't even compile at the momement, see Hovercraft's comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem is that your Car class does not extend JPanel or JComponent or any class that derives from these, and so it cannot be added to your JFrame, and any attempts to do so will result in a compilation error. You have two main possible solutions:

1. Make Car a true component by having it extend JPanel (or JComponent, but I recommend JPanel).
2. Or if you want Car to be a logical class and not a component class, then create a JPanel that contains a Car object and that draw the Car object by directly calling that object's paintComponent method within the JPanel's own paintComponent method.

Other notes:

- You almost always want to call the `super.paintComponent(g)` method within your override so that the JPanel can do housekeeping painting.
- You always want to preface any method that you *think* is an override method with the `@Override` annotation as this way the compiler will warn you if your assumption is incorrect.

e.g.,

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestCar {
    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        Car mainPanel = new Car();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("A Car");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // start all code on the Swing event thread
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}

class Car extends JPanel {
    private static final int PREF_W = 400;
    private static final int PREF_H = 300;
    private static final Rectangle BODY = new Rectangle(0, 10, 60, 20); 
    private static final Line2D ROOF_1 = new Line2D.Double(10, 10, 20, 0);
    private static final Line2D ROOF_2 = new Line2D.Double(20, 0, 40, 0);
    private static final Line2D ROOF_3 = new Line2D.Double(40, 0, 50, 10); 
    private static final Ellipse2D WHEEL_1 = new Ellipse2D.Double(15, 25, 10,10);
    private static final Ellipse2D WHEEL_2 = new Ellipse2D.Double(45, 25, 10,10);

    public Car() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        // draw the rectangle
        g2.draw(BODY);
        g2.draw(ROOF_1);
        g2.draw(ROOF_2);
        g2.draw(ROOF_3);
        g2.draw(WHEEL_1);
        g2.draw(WHEEL_2);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }
}
```

If you want to get real fancy, use a Path2D object, AffineTransform and a Swing Timer and give your GUI a little animation:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Car2 extends JPanel {
    private static final int PREF_W = 400;
    private static final int PREF_H = 300;
    private static final Rectangle BODY = new Rectangle(0, 10, 60, 20);
    private static final Line2D ROOF_1 = new Line2D.Double(10, 10, 20, 0);
    private static final Line2D ROOF_2 = new Line2D.Double(20, 0, 40, 0);
    private static final Line2D ROOF_3 = new Line2D.Double(40, 0, 50, 10);
    private static final Ellipse2D WHEEL_1 = new Ellipse2D.Double(15, 25, 10,
            10);
    private static final Ellipse2D WHEEL_2 = new Ellipse2D.Double(45, 25, 10,
            10);
    private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 30;
    private static final int CAR_DELTA_X = 1;
    private static final int CAR_DELTA_Y = CAR_DELTA_X;
    private Path2D path2D = new Path2D.Double();

    public Car2() {
        path2D.append(BODY, false);
        path2D.append(ROOF_1, false);
        path2D.append(ROOF_2, false);
        path2D.append(ROOF_3, false);
        path2D.append(WHEEL_1, false);
        path2D.append(WHEEL_2, false);

        new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new CarTimerListener()).start();;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.draw(path2D);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    class CarTimerListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            path2D.transform(AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(CAR_DELTA_X, CAR_DELTA_Y));
            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for putting in all this effort for the question. Is there a way to do this without stuff like `Override` or `protected`? I am new to Java. Also can we split up this into two programs? Part 1 ends above `class Car extends JPanel` and part two goes on from there.

Comment: @RegisteredUser: experiment and find out. `@Override` isn't required, but it is smart coding as it will show you immediately the error in your Car class, since your paintComponent class isn't a true override method and will do nothing. Please see latest example for an example of animation fun.

Answer (score 1):

You should only have one main method in your application. I'd change it like below to let the user select which shape to print when running the application.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class DrawFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        if(args[0].equals("face") {

            paintFace()
        }
        else if(args[0].equals("car") {

            paintCar();
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("No Shape Selected to Print");
        }
    }

    private static paintFace() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(300,400);
        frame.setTitle("A Rectangle Object in a JFrame");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Face face = new Face();
        frame.add(face);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static paintCar() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(300,400);
        frame.setTitle("a car");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Car car = new Car();
        frame.add(car);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Also your car does not extend Component. It won't work.

Correct it as

```
public class Car extends JComponent { ... }
```

Comment: Hi, I'd like to clarify, the Car and Face programs are completely separate from each other, there is no relation between them.